# How to visualize the graph using d3Network in R

Tags: r, d3.js, rstudio, sna, networkd3

I'm trying to use a package called d3Network in R to visualize some network and I used the example in R :

```
# Load data
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

# Create graph
d3ForceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source",
               Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
               Group = "group", opacity = 0.4)
```

It only gives me a bunch of scripts rather than a plot. I saw this example on the internet and it seems the others have never come cross this kind of issue. So am I doing something wrong or something is missing? And also I would like to know how to specify the colour of Source nodes and Target nodes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

It seems you are using **d3Network** package which is old and not supported anymore. Try using **networkD3** package.

The function name is: **forceNetwork**

Try this:

```
library(networkD3)
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source",
             Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", opacity = 1)
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried this. It works. The only reason I use 3dNetwork is because there is a argument called zoom. But thanks it is working now.

Comment: there is a `zoom` parameter in `networkD3`'s `forceNetwork` function also (at least in the most recent version (v0.4 as of 2017.09.06)